# Hide parts of HTML form when value = null

Tags: php, html, forms, hide

I made a little voting system for school and I have a problem when a question doesn't have 4 answers.
I want the html form to show only the buttons with a value.
[Screenshot of the voting system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDHv7.png)

Button 3 and 4 are not defined. Only button 1 and 2 should be visible and clickable.

That's my code:

```
<form role="form" class="form-inlinecy" action="VotingVoting.php" method="post">

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" name="a" id="a" value="<?php echo $voting->a ?>"/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" name="b" id="b" value="<?php echo $voting->b ?>"/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" name="c" id="c" value="<?php echo $voting->c ?>"/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" name="d" id="d" value="<?php echo $voting->d ?>"/>
            </div>

        </form>
```

Doesn't sound like a complicated thing to do, but I can't find answers here. Thanks so much!

Greetings
Timo

Comment: Maybe using Angular [ngif directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use PHP Script to check

```
  <?php  if(isset($voting->a) && !empty($voting->a))
    { ?>
       <div class="form-group">
          <input type="submit" name="a" id="a" value="<?php echo $voting->a ?>"/>
       </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

follow the same for all four input fields

Comment: Welcome... @TimoSpringer

Answer (score 1):

You have multiples ways to do it, one could be to add a condition around the input, like this :

```
<?php if($voting->b != ""){ ?>
<div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" name="b" id="b" value="<?php echo $voting->b ?>"/>
            </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Or the CSS way :

```
input[value=""] { display: none; }
```

[See it here](https://jsfiddle.net/y8Lwtg1n/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP conditions as follows to hide the last two buttons if they're not set.

```
<form role="form" class="form-inlinecy" action="VotingVoting.php" method="post">

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" name="a" id="a" value="<?php echo $voting->a ?>"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" name="b" id="b" value="<?php echo $voting->b ?>"/>
    </div>

    <?php if (isset($voting->c)) { ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" name="c" id="c" value="<?php echo $voting->c ?>"/>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if (isset($voting->d)) { ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" name="d" id="d" value="<?php echo $voting->d ?>"/>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using if condition as follow

```
 <?php if(isset($voting->a) && !empty($voting->a)){ ?>
     <div class="form-group">
         <input type="submit" name="a" id="a" value="<?php echo $voting->a ?>"/>
     </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
<form role="form" class="form-inlinecy" action="VotingVoting.php" method="post">

        <div class="form-group">
           <?php
            if($voting->a <> '') { echo '<input type="submit" name="a" id="a" value="'.$voting->a.'"/>';}
           ?>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <?php
            if($voting->b <> '') { echo '<input type="submit" name="b" id="b" value="'.$voting->b.'"/>';}
           ?>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <?php
            if($voting->c <> '') { echo '<input type="submit" name="c" id="c" value="'.$voting->c.'"/>';}
           ?>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <?php
            if($voting->d <> '') { echo '<input type="submit" name="d" id="d" value="'.$voting->d.'"/>';}
           ?>
        </div>

    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```html
<form role="form" class="form-inlinecy" action="VotingVoting.php" method="post">

        <div class="form-group">
           <?php
            if($voting->a != '') { echo '<input type="submit" name="a" id="a" value="'.$voting->a.'"/>';}
           ?>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <?php
            if($voting->b != '') { echo '<input type="submit" name="b" id="b" value="'.$voting->b.'"/>';}
           ?>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <?php
            if($voting->c != '') { echo '<input type="submit" name="c" id="c" value="'.$voting->c.'"/>';}
           ?>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <?php
            if($voting->d != '') { echo '<input type="submit" name="d" id="d" value="'.$voting->d.'"/>';}
           ?>
        </div>

    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

your class structure in general is not very good but for your example

```
<form role="form" class="form-inlinecy" action="VotingVoting.php" method="post">
<?php
foreach (['a','b','c','d'] as $id) {
   if (empty($voting->$id)) continue;?>
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="submit" name="<?php echo $id;?>" id="<?php echo $id;?>" value="<?php echo $voting->$id; ?>"/>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
</form>
```